# Profiling constraint streams score calculation in Optaplanner

Tags: java, profiling, drools, optaplanner, visualvm

I'm looking at profiling the score calculation in my Optaplanner project to find out if there are any hotspots that would benefit from being optimised. However, visualvm shows most of the time to be taken in the self time of `org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluator$InnerEvaluator$_2.evaluate`. I therefore assume that this method is what actually runs a lot of the constraint's code. What is the best way to find out what specific pieces of code are taking the most time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand about Constraint Streams is that it is not imperative programming, and therefore traditional performance optimization techniques such as code profiling are not going to be very helpful. Instead, I suggest you think of Constraint Streams as SQL - the way to have fast SQL is to think about how your data flows, how you join and what gets indexed.

Recently I wrote a blog post explaining the tricks behind [making CS run fast](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/05/25/WritingFastConstraintStreamsSecretRecipe.html). However, CS is internally interpreted by the Drools engine, and therefore studying it may give you [some insights](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#performance-tuning-drl-ref_drl-rules) too. Not all insights there are applicable to CS, but if you take a look at `drools-metric`, you should be able to see which constraints are comparatively slow. And then it becomes a game of tweaking.

Comment: Haskell lends itself very well to code profiling, yet it's definitely not imperative. I understand your message that code profiling isn't very useful with Constraint Streams, but I wouldn't blame the functional paradigm for that.

Comment: You are right. I misspoke in a way - my point was that when debugging a rule engine, there is not a single point in the code where a profiler would help you. Instead, you need to analyze how the engine processes data, and your performance improvements will be coming from that.

Comment: The insights in the blog post and the linked documentation are very helpful. Good answer. +1

Comment: drools-metric tells me that JoinNode(36) is very slow. Could you clarify how I'm supposed to map this to my code? The documentation mentions ReteDumper, but I'm not sure how to use ReteDumper with constraint streams?

Comment: Without understanding your constraints, that is hard to say. It will be one of the join() statements. Doesn't drools-metric usually also output the name of the rule? It should match the name of the constraint in question. If it's not there, the only thing I can think of is to eliminate the constraints one by one and figure out the problematic constraint this way. As far as I know, there is no hook that would allow you to use ReteDumper with CS - but it sounds like a reasonable thing we could eventually add.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Thanks, I'll try that! And no, all drools-metric tells me is a class name from my domain, which I assume is the class the join is happening on. Sadly, that doesn't narrow it down a whole lot as most of my joins are on that class.